# Instalé un modulo con pip y sin embargo no lo puedo usar (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL')

Tags: python-3.x, pillow

instalé Pillow con pip (pip install Pillow), pero el momento de usarlo (from PIL import Image) me da el error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

He buscado varas soluciones sin resultado.

- Python 3.8 (no tengo instalada otra versión de Python)
- Pycharm Comunity Edition 2019.3.3
- Pillow 7.0.0 (instalada en site-packages)

Comment: ¿Por qué no instalas usando Pytcharm directamente? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html. Auque según comentas no tienes más de una versión de Pythoin instalada, es posible aún que Pycharm está usando un entorno virtual que no tiene acceso a system-site-packages por ejemplo.

Comment: Puedes activar tu entorno en la consola y compartirnos la salida del comando `pip freeze --local` así validamos que si tienes instalado Pillow... En mi caso lo tengo corriendo en la versión 3.8.3 y me funciona correctamente.